# time series machine learning prediction every n time steps

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, classification

First of all, I'm new to machine learning, I may have missunderstood some concepts or other things, feel free to acknowledge me if you think so.

I'm using sklearn as ML library,
Suppose I have data with nrows and nfeatures :

```
ID time-interval  feature1  feature2  feature3
1  10             0.10      0.11      0.23
1  20             0.15      0.22      0.17
1  30             0.23      0.58      0.01
2  40             0.27      0.12      0.07
2  50             0.78      0.65      0.15
2  60             0.12      0.17      0.78
3  70             0.22      0.19      0.01
3  80             0.76      0.68      0.25
3  90             0.14      0.14      0.38
```

Here, the ID column is not a feature, it just maps the training set with the targets (solutions). 
In a binary classification context, I need to predict the target, but, I have 1 target every 3 timesteps.
At the end the prediction will looks like :

```
ID Targets
1  0
2  1
3  0
```

It simply means that I have 3 intervals to predict what happens within next three intervals.

How would you approach this time series problem? 
 e.g. how to use the data to make prediction every 3 time steps.
More generally, how to make one prediction with multiple rows?

My first idea were to fit the algorithm with rows that contain 3 rows of the original data by reshaping it (and the end, it multiplies the number of features by 3).
But for sure it isn't the best way to do it since the results were not very predictive..

My second idea were to duplicate the targets :

```
ID Targets
1  0
1  0
1  0
2  1
2  1
2  1
3  0
3  0
3  0
```

And feed the algorithm row by row with the original data.
This is not tested yet.

Comment: It looks like you are just making 1 prediction every 3 time steps, since for all triplets of time steps you only have one class, e.g. ID 4, which I guess will come after ID 3, will have the same label (class, i.e. 0 or 1) for each time step it identifies. If you want to make a prediction with multiple outputs anyway, you just need to pass 1x3 arrays as labels for you algorithm. It won't work for all algos, but it will for example for ANN. As for the results not being predictive using the first approach, that might depend on many factors, for example hyper parameters in the model you use

Comment: @gionni Thank you very much for your answer, but I don't understand everything. :p What do you mean by, "If you want to make a prediction with multiple outputs anyway, you just need to pass 1x3 arrays as labels for you algorithm. "? Can you be more specific please? What do you mean by multiple outputs?

Comment: @gionni when you say "As for the results not being predictive using the first approach, that might depend on many factors, for example hyper parameters in the model you use" does it mean that my first approach is not bad, but I just need to be more carefull with my hyperparameters to make it predictive?

Comment: The first part: a supervised (which I guess is what you are interested into) learning algo takes a matrix/vector/number as input and returns a mtrix/vector/number. In your example, I might guess, you use a matrix as input (e.g., times steps by features) and a n integer (i.e. a label 0 or 1) as output. What you can do, is to use a 1x3 vector of int as output. For some algpritms the result you will obtain might change using this approach. As for the second comment, yes, changing hyperparameters will change the classification result. There could be other causes why the algo doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for you comments, I'll try to investigate in those directions. I know now that my approach is maybe a little bit naive but not so stupid :p. 
Thank you!